# how to plot the second price trade price in a day

Tags: plot, pine-script, trading

I am trying to plot a second traded price after opening. Say at 9.00 the opening price is 1.00. The the second price done at 1.01 which is different from the opening price of 1.00. I can do it in per
1 range, and try to find the second price. But when I try the daily, i  cannot get it.

I don't know the script ok not. I swith it to 1R resolution, its ok. how to let is change to 15Min but the second price to be on 1R. Or how to print the second price only on first bar.

```
highTimeFrame = "1R"
sessSpec = "0700-1800"

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)

var float s1 = na //open
var float s2 = na  //second price
var float s3 = na // current close
if newbar
    s1 := open
    s3 := close[1]
    if high != open
        s2 := high
    if low != open  
        s2 := low 
        
plot(s1, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=color.red)
plot(s2, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=color.blue)
plot(s3, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: which language/library? you should add those tags

Comment: i am using pine script . Sorry i dont put the tag